# How do I get the Average response time in Jmeter 3.0 Dashboard

Tags: jmeter

In the Jmeter 3.0 Report Dashboard the Statistics table appears to be missing the average response time column. Min, Max, 90th pct, 95 pct and 99 pct response times along with Label, #Samples, KO(?), Error%, Throughput and KB/sec columns are present, but Average is not.

The Statistics table in the documentation at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html also shows Average as missing.

How do I generate the average response time in the Report Dashboard Statistics Table?

Answer (score 0):

Average response time is not available in this report as it is a misleading metric.
As of 3.0 it is not here, it may be added in the future if many people ask for it, see:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Comment: The merits or demerits of average response time as a metric notwithstanding and short of a future enhancement, how do I generate the average response time in the Report Dashboard Statistics Table?